# Can we use Deep Neural Network model for Linearly separable models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Given a single feature linearly separable dataset, can we use DNNs? I know that we should not use DNN for such simple tasks, but I wonder if its even possible.

For example, if I have a Height Dataset which consists of height in cm ranging from 100 to 200cm and I classify a person as Tall if the height is more then 150cm.

Can we use DNN to classify these heights?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Y

Comment: I used 2 hidden layer DNN: H1:10 neurons, H2:20 neurons and 2 neurons in final layer, the model did not get trained